# Sluggish behaviour with li:hover with Cufon

Tags: css, hover, cufon

Edit: Found out that this happens even though Cufon isn't even applied!
Edit2: My bad, looks like Cufon is creating the slowless afterall.
However, removing the line where I replace the menuwrapper font style with Cufon still results in sluggish behaviour. So it doesn't seem like it's got anything to do with applying cufon to the lists themselves.

---

Hi, I'm using Cufon to "embed" a custom font to my site. And this font is used on the main menu and I've encountered a bug or something where setting the height, padding or anything of the li:hover makes IE go sluggish. I don't know why this happens but the problem dissapears when I remove the property from the li:hover. It works fine in Firefox though.

So my question is, is there another way of getting around this?

What I'm basically trying to do is to position the li:hover because it has a background to it. And I want to skew it a few pixels towards the bottom.

My CSS looks like this:

```
  #menuwrapper {
 float:right;
 margin-top:10px;
 height: 65px;
}

.menuwrapper li {
 float:right;
 list-style: none;
 margin-top:10px;
 padding-top:18px;   
 padding-left: 23px;
 padding-right: 23px;
 height:23px; 
}

.menuwrapper a{
 font-family:georgia;
 font-size:22px;
 color:#ebebeb;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.menuwrapper li:hover {
 background-image: url(img/MenuHover.png);
 padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not understand what you mean exactly but as you said you want to get it a bit lower at the bottom, then you can do that with **margin-top** css property.

```
margin-top:10px; /* down it by 10 pixels */
```

Comment: Yes, but this results in sluggish behaviour of the li:hover.
In fact, setting ANY padding, margin, height or width property seems to cause slowdown. Even if I haven't even applied Cufon to the list itself. As long as Cufon is on the page at all, every li:hover item has sluggish behavour nomatter what. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to lay this one dead I guess. Getting nowhere with it as it is now.